# Amazon MWS feed API Issue, to cancel orders

Tags: xml, amazon-mws

please help me out for this. I am trying long back to cancel Amazon order via MWS Feed API. But it is not canceling at all.
Feed submission and all is successfully working, but the order is not canceling.
Below is my Feed XML,
We are using Report type both I tried:
_POST_ORDER_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_DATA_,
_POST_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_DATA_

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>My Store</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>OrderAcknowledgement</MessageType>
    <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OrderAcknowledgement>
    <AmazonOrderID>050-1234567-1234567</AmazonOrderID>
    <StatusCode>Failure</StatusCode>
    </OrderAcknowledgement>
    </Message>
   </AmazonEnvelope>
```

Comment: **Started bounty to get answers.  Thank You. This answer has been outdated because the api endpoint has been expired. can someone kindly confirm if this endpoint will be used going forward? https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feeds-api-v2021-06-30-reference#cancelfeed**

Answer (score 0):

You have to cancel the items to cancel the order. Try this:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>ANZE9ABCDEFGH</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>OrderAcknowledgement</MessageType> 
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OrderAcknowledgement>
            <AmazonOrderID>ORDER ID</AmazonOrderID>
            <StatusCode>Failure</StatusCode>
            <Item> 
                <AmazonOrderItemCode>ASIN</AmazonOrderItemCode>
                <CancelReason>REASON</CancelReason>
            </Item>
        </OrderAcknowledgement>
    </Message> 
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Valid reason codes:

- NoInventory
- ShippingAddressUndeliverable
- CustomerExchange
- BuyerCanceled
- GeneralAdjustment
- CarrierCreditDecision
- RiskAssessmentInformationNotValid
- CarrierCoverageFailure
- CustomerReturn
- MerchandiseNotReceived

If you don't store ASINs in your order management system you can use `<MerchantOrderItemID>` in place of `AmazonOrderItemCode`

Here's a copy of the [schema definition](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/OrderAcknowledgement.xsd)

Comment: <MerchantIdentifier> is the merchantID?

Comment: Yes, I believe it should be. That's how the MWS system will identify your store and update the records appropriately

Comment: It is not working, I tried with ASIN and OrderID  with Merchant ID. But still not working. Will it take some time to to update in AMazon site?

Comment: Yes, it can definitely take a while for Amazon to process feeds. Did this feed send anything back when you submitted it?

Comment: Yes, we are getting submit feed id return back. (FeedSubmissionID).

Comment: I remember there being a place in Seller Central to view your feed process reports. I don't currently have access to a seller account so I'm afraid I can't tell you where to looks specifically.