# Cancel orders with amazon sp-api

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

Since you can cancel orders programmatically with the (old) MWS api, I was trying to figure out how to implement the same functionality via (the new) SP-APIs, but couldn't wrap  my head around it, because by looking at the [documentation](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/orders-api-v0-reference), there aren't any methods available to delete orders.

Just for reference:
This is an answer that shows how it was implemented with the old APIs

[Amazon MWS feed API Issue, to cancel orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479604/amazon-mws-feed-api-issue-to-cancel-orders)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Feeds - just the same as you did in MWS - similiar to the example you shared.
https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feed-type-values

Order Acknowledgement Feed